# Testing Lambda Function to fullfill Chatbot request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am new to AWS LAmbda, Chatbots,  and Javascript.:
Ultimately, I am trying to create a chatbot that will make a rest API call (POST) using the value in the slot when the lambda function fulfills the request from the chatbot. I have the lambda code that makes the rest API call working fine in a separate function currently.

I learning and am trying to get the lambda function to fullfill the chatbot request with my below test function:

When I do  a test in the chatbot  to the test lambda function, I am getting the following error:
**An error has occurred: The server encountered an error processing the Lambda response**

when I tested the payload inside lambda  it worked. however,  it is not working when I test the chatbot with the same lambda function. I created the lambda function based on the info on this response format page, but I cannot figure out what I am missing in the code.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

Here is the request:

```
{
  "alternativeIntents": [],
  "botVersion": "$LATEST",
  "dialogState": "ConfirmIntent",
  "intentName": "Hello",
  "message": "are you sure your name is al?",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sentimentResponse": {
    "sentimentLabel": "NEUTRAL",
    "sentimentScore": "{Positive: 0.031974494,Negative: 0.023143388,Neutral: 0.8841075,Mixed: 0.06077461}"
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "sessionId": "2021-07-25T14:18:31.085Z-OxCrkGGA",
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": {
    "name": "al"
  }
}
```

Here is my lambda code for the test(Node JS):

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {  

   callback(null, {
       "dialogAction":{
           "type":"Close",
           "fullfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
           "message": {
               "contentType":"PlainText",
               "content":"Your request  has been fulfilled"
            }
       }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, then consider using the **AWS SDK for JavaScript** to invoke Amazon LEX. There is an end to end tutorial that will step you through this use case.

[Building an Amazon Lex chatbot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lex-bot-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the spelling of one of the properties.

`fullfillmentState` should be written as `fulfillmentState`.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {  
   callback(null, {
       "dialogAction":{
           "type":"Close",
           "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
           "message": {
               "contentType":"PlainText",
               "content":"Your request  has been fulfilled"
            }
       }
   });
};
```

I've made the change to your original function and tested it; above is the working sample.